# How to solve System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, ms-word

I am trying to read contents from a word document(.docx) into a string variable. I have written the following code for the same.

```
 private void readFileContent(string path)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordApp = new ApplicationClass();

        object file = path;
        object readOnly = false;
        object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file, ref miss,ref readOnly,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss,ref miss);

        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
       string  resumetext = doc.Content.Text;
        doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
        wordApp.Quit(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
    }
```

But there is error in the "wordApp.Documents.Open()". The error is as follows..[image]

But I have the file in the same location.[image]

1. I tried running the application in ADMINISTRATOR MODE also in case
   there was some issue with accessing the document, still no luck.
2. When I tried the full path i.e
   @"C:\Users\WINDOWS02\Desktop\WebSite2\NewOfinityTradingSite\Test\"
   instead of "~\Test\" , the word document is not getting uploaded to
   the specified folder even while uploading it.

Please provide me some input. Browsing the error code didn't gave me any useful info..

Comment: As suggested in the (unreadable) exception bitmap you posted, you can check the HRESULT (the COM error code). It may help diagnosis

Comment: Are you passing in the full path to the file, or simply the filename?  If the executing assembly (your website) is not in `WebSite2\NewOfinityTradingSite\Test` but is instead say in `Website2\NewOfinityTradingSite\Text\bin\debug` or something like that **and** you're only using the filename, it won't find the file, as it will be looking for the file in the same directory the executing assembly is in.

Comment: I am using @"C:\Users\WINDOWS02\Desktop\WebSite2\NewOfinityTradingSite\Test\" as the path.